# How is a number with measure unit named

Tags: translation, mathematics

I am trying to figure out how a number together with measure unit name could be called as a whole. "Named number" is definitely not the right term.

Examples:

- 20,5 m
- 15 kg
- -17 °C
- 0,00073 kg/L/°C

The question is about the name of those numbers in mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this use, a **[measurement](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/measurement)** is a quantity of units, like two meters, four pounds, or 30 seconds.

> **[measurement](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/measurement)**
>
> 2 [count] : a size, length, or amount known by measuring something
>
> *The room's measurements are 30 by 15 feet.*

Comment: It seems to be a little bit weird for me. Measurement is the physical thing, isn't it? I am asking about how these numbers are named in mathematics. But if you insist on plausibility of this answer ...

Comment: I don't know about usage [specific to mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions), but in the English language, each of your examples (20,5 m, 15 kg, -17 °C, 0,00073 kg/L/°C) are measurements. **"6"** is a number; **"6m"** is a measurement.